# Insert XML file into Oracle table

Tags: xml, oracle

I have XML file containing 13 columns. I want to load the file in Oracle table which has same columns as the file.
I tried inserting it with external table. It loads half the number of records in XML file as some tags are missing

I get the error message in log file as

KUP-04021: field formatting error for field PREVIOUSCUSTOMEREXPERIENCE
KUP-04035: beginning enclosing delimiter not found
KUP-04101: record 445 rejected in file E:\Oracle\Reddy_Test_Dir\resources.xml

For this record the tag    was missing in the XML file.

Can anybody suggest some way how to load all these records

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you provide some sample data .. I would say to have the xml formatted or convert it to a CSV or something.

Answer (score 1):

### Where is the problem.

I think you are defined the external table in that way.

```
create table bleble ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL belbe...
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
      RECORDS DELIMITED BY '</row>'
      FIELDS (
         Col1 CHAR(100) ENCLOSED BY '<Name>' AND '</Name>',
         col2 CHAR(100) ENCLOSED BY '<Name2>' AND '</Name2>')
  )
```

And xml looks like

```
<rowset>
  <row>
    <name>aa</name>
    <name2>aa</name2>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>bb</name>
  </row>
</rowset>
```

External table can't find  enclosing delimiter for col2 and it throw error.

My recommendation is to look for other way to deal with xml.

1. DBMS_XMLSTORE or DBMS_XMLSAVE.
2. Oracel XDB repository. (quite hard)
3. Import and save document in xmltype. And xmltype can be processed by xmltable.